# How to calculate efficient minimum distance in Python (regression)

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, scipy.stats

I was wondering if it was possible to calculate the efficient minimum distance estimator b_emd in Python using statsmodels or scipy or such packages. I know its possible to do by hand just with matrix multiplication but I wanted to know if there was a better way.

Comment: scipy.spatial.distance.cdist ?

Comment: That's too vague and general. Which minimum distance estimator? For which type of data? Which kind of model? ...  If you can do it by hand, then show an example.

Comment: Well, I was just wondering if there was something similar to, for example, smf.ols but instead of for OLS for a general minimum distance estimator like R has [here](https://rdrr.io/rforge/distrMod/man/MDEstimator.html).